# How to order when using partition by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to assign a row number to every row where data is ordered by date and I want to restart assigning from 0 when column "project_name" changes and column "ok_criterium" changes.

DDL:

```
  CREATE TABLE TEST1 
   ("PROJECT_NAME" NUMBER, 
    "OK_CRITERIUM" NUMBER, 
    "DDATE" DATE
   ) ;
```

Data:

```
Insert into test1 (PROJECT_NAME,OK_CRITERIUM,DDATE) values ('241','1',to_date('21.12.2019 00:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into test1 (PROJECT_NAME,OK_CRITERIUM,DDATE) values ('241','1',to_date('21.12.2019 00:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into test1 (PROJECT_NAME,OK_CRITERIUM,DDATE) values ('241','0',to_date('26.12.2019 00:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into test1 (PROJECT_NAME,OK_CRITERIUM,DDATE) values ('241','0',to_date('26.12.2019 00:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into test1 (PROJECT_NAME,OK_CRITERIUM,DDATE) values ('241','1',to_date('01.01.2020 00:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into test1 (PROJECT_NAME,OK_CRITERIUM,DDATE) values ('241','0',to_date('01.01.2020 00:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'));
```

My select:

```
select 
row_number () over (partition by project_name,ok_criterium order by ddate asc ) as rn,
t1.*
from test1 t1
```

Result:

```
RN PROJECT_NAME OK_CRITERIUM DDATE 
1   241 0   26.12.2019 00:00:00
2   241 0   26.12.2019 00:00:00
3   241 0   01.01.2020 00:00:00
1   241 1   21.12.2019 00:00:00
2   241 1   21.12.2019 00:00:00
3   241 1   01.01.2020 00:00:00
```

Problem:
Row is not ordered by column ddate. You can see date 21.12.2019 after date 26.12.2019.
Data is also ordered by "ok_criterium" which I don't want.

What I need:

```
RN PROJECT_NAME OK_CRITERIUM DDATE 
1 241   1   21.12.2019 00:00:00
2 241   1   21.12.2019 00:00:00
1 241   0   26.12.2019 00:00:00
2 241   0   26.12.2019 00:00:00
1 241   1   01.01.2020 00:00:00
1 241   0   01.01.2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: You have rows with duplicate data. Any row number generation strategy won't be "stable". It will change every time you run the query. You'll need to identify some column to differentiate the rows.

Comment: Yes that's why I'm using use row_number to identify duplicate data. But I need to order it by date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query. You have to partition by date as well.

```
select 
row_number () over (partition by project_name,ok_criterium, ddate order by ddate asc ) 
as rn,
t1.*
from test1 t1 order by ddate;
```

Below is the demo,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e08000697ced91ee3e1df392ba0d8ac9

Comment: When I incude ddate into partition clause, then row_number changes also when ddate changes. So the result is different than i need:
```
1 241 1 21.12.2019 00:00:00
2 241 1 21.12.2019 00:00:00
1 241 0 26.12.2019 00:00:00
2 241 0 26.12.2019 00:00:00
1 241 0 01.01.2020 00:00:00 ---I need here rn = 2 because "no change" in ok_criterium, when you include ddate into partition clause it will "restart" counter
1 241 1 01.01.2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: It does not change. You can see the demo i have provided, you have your expected result

Comment: Even though I consider the question flawed, this solution works.

Comment: @piedro, then please prove the proper data set, so that can help you on the solution. As per your data set, provided solution is having proper result as expected

Comment: Please check in your question on your expected result, what you have provided. If that is not your expected result please change it

Answer (score 0):

Considering your requirement, you should include ddate in your partitioning clause. Also you need to sort the result with ddate.

```
select t2. from (select 
row_number () over (partition by project_name,ok_criterium, ddate order by ddate asc) as rn,
t1.*
from test1 t1) t2 order by ddate asc;
```